# Explicit concurrent copying GC freed, Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I want to create the data model asynchronously. I am using MVVM.
My code looks like this.

**class Page (code behind):**

```
public partial class PageMusicPlayerView : TabbedPage
{
    public PageMusicPlayerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PageMusicPlayerViewModel viewModel = PageMusicPlayerViewModel.GetInstance();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await PageMusicPlayerViewModel.GetInstance().InitAsync();
    }

}
```

**class PageMusicPlayerViewModel (view model):**

```
public class PageMusicPlayerViewModel : NotifyProperty
{
    private static PageMusicPlayerViewModel instance = null;

    public static PageMusicPlayerViewModel GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new PageMusicPlayerViewModel();

        }
        return instance;
    }

    public MusicPlaylistModel MusicPlaylist { get; set; } = MusicPlaylistModel.GetInstance();

    public async Task InitAsync()
    {
        await MusicPlaylist.InitAsync();
    }

}
```

**class MusicPlaylistModel (model):**

```
public class MusicPlaylistModel : NotifyProperty
{
    private static MusicPlaylistModel instance = null;

    ObservableCollection<MusicItemModel> _listMusic;

    public ObservableCollection<MusicItemModel> ListMusic
    {
        get { return _listMusic; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _listMusic, value); }
    } 

    public static MusicPlaylistModel GetInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new MusicPlaylistModel();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private MusicPlaylistModel()
    {
        ListMusic = new ObservableCollection<MusicItemModel>();
    }

    public async Task InitAsync()
    {
        int size = 8000;
        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
        {
            ListMusic.Add(new MusicItemModel { SoundName = "TEST" });
        }
    }
 
}
```

**class MusicItemModel (model):**

```
public class MusicItemModel : NotifyProperty
{
    long _id = -1;
    string _soundName = string.Empty;
    string _soundDuration = string.Empty;
    bool _cached = false;
    string _downloadingLabel = string.Empty;

    public long Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    }
    public string SoundName
    {
        get { return _soundName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _soundName, value); }
    }
    public string SoundDuration
    {
        get { return _soundDuration; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _soundDuration, value); }
    }
    public bool Cached
    {
        get { return _cached; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _cached, value); }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public string DownloadingLabel
    {
        get { return _downloadingLabel; }
        set 
        {
            SetProperty(ref _downloadingLabel, value); 
        }
    }

}
```

Model `ListMusic` is bound to a view.
I provide the `MusicItemModel` class as is, everything else is reduced to a minimal example.
I am getting errors while running the application. Also, the debugger starts to freeze a lot:

```
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 9420(1219KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 71% free, 2406KB/8550KB, paused 33us total 10.883ms
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 717(39KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 72% free, 2382KB/8526KB, paused 24us total 8.730ms
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 15(48KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 72% free, 2382KB/8526KB, paused 20us total 8.058ms
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 72% free, 2382KB/8526KB, paused 24us total 8.521ms
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 6(32KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 72% free, 2382KB/8526KB, paused 24us total 8.279ms
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 72% free, 2382KB/8526KB, paused 22us total 8.190ms
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 72% free, 2382KB/8526KB, paused 22us total 8.067ms
Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 32(48KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 72% free, 2382KB/8526KB, paused 22us total 7.973ms
```

Errors are only under debugging in Visual Studio.
If I run a debug build without debugging everything works fine and fast. Why is this happening?
Android 10, Huawei P30.

P.S.:
If I reduce the size of the variable `size` to 1000 and below, then the problems go away. But the amount of my data in the real sample is 8276 elements.

Comment: Those aren’t errors. Those messages are normal. Regarding performance, when debugger is attached certain operations are slower. (No JIT optimization.) Necessary, so that if an exception occurs, debugger can stop at exact line. Do not be concerned about performance when debugger is attached. Bottom line: what you have described is okay, no reason to be concerned.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Sorry, but the application lags a lot and it is not possible to debug it

Comment: You have an ObservableCollection with 8000 elements. That's the fundamental problem, as you discovered. That represents a whole musical score? Just load some limited part of the music, then "page" to the next part, as needed. Maintain a `List<MusicItemModel> AllMusicItems` with all 8000. Have a `startIndex` for the section you are displaying in `ObservableCollection ListMusic`. With `const int MaxItems = ...;` controlling how much you load at one time. Make `MaxItems` smaller while debugging.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The elements of the collection store only the name of the song. The byte array itself is unloaded from the server on demand. The size of this collection is ~ 600 kb. I found the solution to the problem here:. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5752 . It's about hot reload.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting. If you [UNCHECK Hot Reload in Tools/Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload), does that fix the performance problem?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes :)

Comment: I thought it might be hot reload, but I have the same basic issue with a bound ObservableCollection, and disabling Hot Reload makes no difference. GC still occurring at just as slow a pace, while UI is completely blocked. I'm on dotnet MAUI but it's still Xamarin/Mono under the hood. I imagine it's slower in Debug but it seems like the Android implementation of this stuff is just not suitable for handling major changes in a bound collection. Even if it's not Observable and you initialize it once with a giant List, it will try to allocate item by item, while blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extreme lagginess with an ObservableCollection having 8000 elements, was due to `Hot Reload`.

[UNCHECK Hot Reload in Tools/Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload) resolved the performance issue.